# Is there a commutative ring $R$ with an idempotent endomorphism $f$ that cannot be expressed as $f(x)=sx$ for some idempotent $s \in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any element $s$ of a commutative monoid $M$, the following are equivalent.

1. idempotency (that is, $s^2=s$).
2. self-distributivity (that is, $s(xy) = (sx)(sy)$ for all $x,y \in M$).
3. the function $M \rightarrow M$ given by $x \mapsto sx$ is a monoid endomorphism.

Now suppose that $M$ also has the structure of a commutative ring. Then the above conditions are equivalent to:

4. the function $f:M \rightarrow M$ given by $x \mapsto sx$ is a ring endomorphism.

Note that such an $f$ will necessarily be idempotent, in the sense that $f \circ f = f$. A natural question is therefore whether or not every idempotent endomorphism arises in this way.

> **Question.** Does there exist a commutative ring $R$ together with an idempotent endomorphism $f : R \rightarrow R$ that cannot be expressed
>   as $f(x)=sx$ for some idempotent $s \in R$?

The obvious thing to try is to fix a commutative ring $R$, and consider the endomorphism $f : R \times R \rightarrow R \times R$ given by $f(x,y) = (x,0)$. Unfortunately this doesn't work, because $f(x,y) = (1,0)(x,y)$ and $(1,0)$ is idempotent.

Comment: Wouldn't any homomorphism $R[X]$ to $R[X]$ that sends $X$ to an element of the base ring $R$ and all elements of $R$ to themselves work?  ($R$ a commutative ring-with-a-one, $R[X]$ the polynomial ring in one variable over $R$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homomorphism evaluating elements of $R[x]$ at zero, composed with the inclusion map from $R\to R[x]$ is an idempotent ring endomorphism.

If R has no nilpotent elements, then the only idempotents of a polynomial ring are constants that are idempotent, you can see this map is not induced by an idempotent element.

Comment: This does answer the question, because (for example) we can assume that $R$ is an integral domain. But, is it really true that every idempotent in a polynomial ring is constant? This seems too good to be true. For example, what if $R$ has nilpotent elements? We should be able to find idempotents in $R[X]$ that are not elements of $R$, methinks.

Comment: @goblin Oh, sure I guess we need at least that R has no nilpotent elements to make the claim.

Comment: @goblin I had been inconsistently thinking of R in general and as a field.